# Is Indenting the same as Whitespacing?

Tags: python

"The following lines are **indented** to show that they apart of the "hello" function."

and also, what is the difference between a **variable** and a **function**?

Comment: Is the sentence in quotation marks a quote? If so, please provide a link or name the source, so that we can look at it in context.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Wikipedia's definition of 'Indentation'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_%28typesetting%29), at ['Dive into Python''s section on indenting code](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html).

Answer (score 2):

[A Python function is a value/object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_Python) that represents code can be 'called' (or run) when using a [function call `(..)`expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls) (which is not to be confused with grouping parenthesis).

A variable [is a 'binding' (or name) for a value](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding); when evaluated it will return the 'last assigned' value.

Thus in `fn()`, `fn` is a *variable* (really 'binding') that evaluates to a *function* object/value which is then invoked.
 (Any expression can have the call operator applied; and it might not be a variable.)

---

And I have no idea what the start of the 'first question' is about ..